# How to make all the segments of the UISegmentedControl selected on the click of a button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application in which I have a segmented control with seven segments in it. I have a button nearby to my segmented control. I want that when I click on my button all my segments of the segmented control should remain selected.

Comment: Only one segment of a UISegmentedControl can be selected at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible as it is segmented control. You can create custom buttons and add images as background image to buttons and handle same. This can make you work easy.

Comment: @Rani : Its as simple as dragging UIButton to your project and you need seven custom buttons and creating segmented like images and then when you press your Button just set all your custom button images of selected type.. Hope it helps you...

Answer (score 0):

A UISegmentedControl isn't meant to work like that, ie to have multiple selections. 
It might be possible to override it, but I would recommend instead creating your own custom control, or perhaps create an array of Buttons or Switches.

Comment: could u provide any sample code on how to handle multiple selection of butons